# scanForPeripheralsWithServices on iOS not finding devices by service UUID

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I am using scanForPeripheralsWithServices to scan for devices by service UUID. When I use some of the standard service UUID values it will work sometimes.

When I try to use custom service UUIDs it often won't find any devices, but if I use nil for the service UUID list it will find those same devices that it doesn't find when I use their service UUID.

What is going on? Could it be because the advertising packet for the devices can only advertise some of its services?

Comment: The set services advertised by a peripheral is often smaller than the services offered by a peripheral.  This is because there is limited space in the advertisement so it makes sense to advertise the "primary" service.  For example a Heart rate device may offer the heart rate service, the device information service and the battery service, but it will only advertise the heart rate service as this is service that other devices will be "interested in".  Once they have identified the device and connected to it they can discover the device info and battery services if they want

Comment: This app is a useful test tool - https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/lightblue-explorer-bluetooth/id557428110?mt=8 if it can find your devices then you may suspect your code.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking it was probably the limited size of the advertising packet. I will try out that utility and see what it reports. Please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of services advertised by a peripheral is typically smaller than the services it offers. This is because there is limited space in the advertisement so it makes sense to advertise only the "primary" service.

From the [Apple Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForSettingUpYourIOSDeviceAsAPeripheral/BestPracticesForSettingUpYourIOSDeviceAsAPeripheral.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH5-SW1) -

> There are also limits as to how much space you can use when advertising
>   data. When your app is in the foreground, it can use up to 28 bytes of
>   space in the initial advertisement data for any combination of the two
>   supported advertising data keys. If this space is used up, there are
>   an additional 10 bytes of space in the scan response that can be used
>   only for the local name. Any service UUIDs that do not fit in the
>   allotted space are added to a special “overflow” area; they can be
>   discovered only by an iOS device that is explicitly scanning for them.
>   While your app is in the background, the local name is not advertised
>   and all service UUIDs are place in the overflow area.
>
> To help you stay within these space constraints, limit the service
>   UUIDs you advertise to those that identify your primary services.

As an example, a Heart rate device may offer the heart rate service, the device information service, the battery service and more, but it will only advertise the heart rate service as this is service that other devices will be "interested in" as it distinguishes this device from other classes of device.

Once the device has been identified and a connection established the other services can be discovered if required.